# Lemon are Sour Orange with many sharp thorns

Tags: diagnosis, grafting

Yields Hundred r better Orange color fruit. It could produce Alam if you can feel me. I'm wanting the fruit it produces to be consumed instead of a tripping in rotten Orange/ Lemon slip n slide!!! I can take a picture of said tree as it's doing like it's been many years .(20). Surviving quite a few freezes on the backside of kthe house for Protection. Also sharp throws on branch limbs n hurt like hell when stuck. Not mower friendly r any tires.Hopeless wanting a bearer to my fruit??? Sweet please

Comment: So, you have a productive citrus tree, but you don't like the fruit it produces, and want better fruit from the tree?  Did I get you right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are writing.  What is the problem and what is your question?

Comment: Supporting the earlier comments, we also need picture if you are not sure that it is a lemon tree. Plus, what do you want to know about those thorns ? And what about grafting?

Answer (score 3):

Yes I feel you Caribbean king man (Bahamian?). You have citrus tree that used to bear good fruit now bad fruit with thorns. Dat tree is grafted, and now a sprout from the root has grown up and take over tree. You can see the bottom of the tree where comes the bad sprout. You could cut out bad sprout and see if what remains of the good side of the tree can be strong again. Lotsa work there, but maybe good result.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently (question a bit hard to make out as presently written) you have a citrus tree with sharp thorns that produces bitter oranges.

You should be able to use that tree as a rootstock to **graft** less thorny and sweeter varieties of citrus to. You can attempt grafting multiple different varieties even, though maintaining such a tree can be a bit of work, as usually one variety will tend to take over, if left to itself.

Some citrus grafting questions and answers:

[Can I graft a Navel or Valencia orange tree onto an established citrus tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4721/6806)

[Can I graft a branch of a sweet orange onto a sour orange tree to get sweet fruit?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/14553/6806)

[Can I graft a citrus using two different techniques simultaneously?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/55818/6806)

[Why does the lime half of a grafted tree suffer, while the lemon half thrives?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/29531/6806)

[Can a lemon tree become an orange tree?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/9576/6806)